# How to create a java application which can be run as window service?

Tags: java, service, rmi

I need your advice on creating a Java application which can be used to run as a service. I am using Java service wrapper to install and run it as a service in windows. 
I have 2 classes ServiceApp.java & RMIService.java. ServiceApp has main method and RMIService will be a server running to accept connection from client..

Now here is my problem. From my main method, as soon as I create RMIService, the main thread will exit and application halts which is correct. Since I wanted to block the main thread to run it as a service, I created a SocketServer and Socket object and called Socket.accept(). This works fine and service is running as main thread gets blocked but I am not convinced that this is the correct approach. Please provide me the right way to do this . Here is a code snippet :

```
public class ServiceApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting RMI server");
        {
            RMIService rmiService;
            try {
                rmiService = new RemoteServerService();
                Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099); 
                registry.rebind("RMIServer", rmiService);
                System.out.println("RMI server running");
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket( 7000 );
            while ( true )
            {
                socket = serverSocket.accept(); //This will block the main thread

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                if (socket != null)
                    socket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS : I had searched Stackoverflow on these questions but couldn't find any that matched with my requirement.

Comment: @Duncan Looks like you have removed it already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export any remote object, including the Registry, one or more *non-daemon* listener threads are created to listen to the port(s) concerned. These will prevent the process from exiting. You don't need to do anything further, and you certainly don't need an otherwise pointless `ServerSocket.`

However you do need to prevent the exported remote objects from being garbage-collected, which will unexport them. You need to keep static references to both the Registry and your own remote object(s).

Comment: Could you please give me an example on your last point. "You need to keep static references to both the Registry and your own remote object(s)"

Comment: @Learner Your `Registry` and `RMIService` references are both local variables. Make them static variables. I really decline to believe that you need an example.

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. I learnt on static references and RMI today. I will post my modified code so that it could help others as an example.

Comment: You didn't know about static variables? Really?

Comment: I knew about the static variables but didn't know that I could hold the RMIServer using that :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code to make it working. Thanks to EJP for the solution.

**ServiceApp.java**

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class ServiceApp {
  public static RMIService rmiService;
  public static Registry registry;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Starting RMI server");
    {

        try {
            rmiService = new RMIService();
             registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099); 
            registry.rebind("RMIServer", rmiService);
            System.out.println("RMI server running");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

  }
}
```

**RMIService.java**

```
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;



public class RMIService extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IRemoteServerService
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public RMIService() throws RemoteException {
    super();
     // Install a security manager.
    System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());

}
public String pingTest()
{
    return "Server says hi";
}
@Override
public boolean resetService() throws RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

**IRemoteServerService**

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
public interface IRemoteServerService extends Remote {


boolean resetService() throws RemoteException;
String pingTest() throws RemoteException;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but when you bind RMIService to the registry you don't need to block main as the rmiservice gets daemonized. So you just don't need to block the main thread.

Comment: I am really not sure about this one. But even if we consider that RMIservice gets daemonized, my main application ServiceAPp would just halt and thereby windows service terminates. I wanted windows service to be running and ServiceApp should be running always.

Comment: I've been trying with the Thread package, so i think you will like this, 1st you make a function in RMIServcie class like so public Thread getThread() { return Thread.currentThread();}, from App use Thread tr = rmiService.getThread() and whenever you want to block use tr.join(); so when rmiService dies main dies too

Comment: that works too :). Thank you. However the question is still open. Is this the way it should be done? or do we have any alternatives?

Comment: Several things wrong here. 'Daemonized' is entirely the wrong word, and RMI listener thread creation happens on export, not bind. However @Learner your statement "even if we consider that RMIservice gets daemonized, my main application ServiceAPp would just halt" doesn't even begin to make sense. The *non*-daemon RMI threads prevent that from happening.